# Axios loading API, can't reference API in the DOM afterwards, "TypeError: this.state.products.map is not a function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am loading a local API using Axios. On the .then, if I console.log the result, I get the result just fine in my console.

I then assign it to state under the name 'products'. In the DOM, if I try and reference it, I get the error:

```
TypeError: this.state.products.map is not a function
```

What reason could there be for this? I wrapped the API call in a ComponentWillMount() and it still doesn't work.

Here is my code:

App.js

```
import axios from "axios"
import React from "react"

// const api = axios.create({
//   baseURL: `http://localhost/api/`,
// })

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      products: [],
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("http://localhost/api/").then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data)
      this.setState({ products: res.data })
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.products.map((product) => (
          <div>
            <h1>{product.id}</h1>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

Comment: care to share with us the 'console.log(res.data)' output?
Also, think you should verify that data is in the proper format before setting the state

Comment: App.js:18 {window: Array(4), door: Array(3), roof: Array(1)}

no point opening it but it is what I expected, three arrays from my backend database

Comment: The output means your response is not an Array but an Object, so you cannot use `map` to iterate. What exactly do you want to render in page?

Comment: Okay, for eg, within the "Door" array, there is a prop called "ID". So ideally, I would like to map through "Products" using something like this.state.products[door].map, so I can use something like "<h1>{product.id}</h1>" something along those lines?

Answer (score 0):

Verify what you have in `res.data`: mb it's a JSON-string and you need to parse it first, or it's an `object`, but it should be array.

Comment: the output is App.js:18 {window: Array(4), door: Array(3), roof: Array(1)}

Comment: As you see, it's an object, not array, that's why you have this error :)

Comment: Oh! So how can I fix it if you don't mind explaining :) ?

Comment: I think your API should return an array of products. If not, you can just do this.setState({ products: Object.values(res.data) })

Comment: Okay well, that got rid of the error, but how can I display it? For eg, if I wanted to display the door array's prop, subproduct?

Comment: Now your `product` variable inside of `.map` contains all your properties (`window`, `door`, `roof`) and you can simply run through any of it via `product.door.forEach(d => {//do-something-here})`

Comment: Hmmm that doesn't seem to be working?

Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Comment: Hm, in this case you can just store an object as you did before `this.setState({ products: res.data })` and traverse through via `this.state.products.door.map()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229775/discussion-between-vlad-diachenko-and-donnie-berry).